# How to use fgets() without resulting in bug and also include '.' in the same line of the output?

Tags: c, input, scanf, fgets

I'm learning and practicing **'C'**. Using **fgets()** function has been a challenge for me. For example, the below code is running absolutely fine. When I run this piece of code, it takes my mom's name (firstName lastName) as input but the '.' is being placed on the next line. How can I get the period on the same line of the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char motherName[30];
    printf("Enter your mother's full name: ");
    fgets(motherName, sizeof(motherName), stdin);
    printf("Your mom's full name is %s.", motherName);
    
    return 0;
}
```

There's also another query. When using fgets() function along with other variable inputs, it's leading to a bug. The first two inputs are taken in properly and outputs are exactly the way that I wanted it. But when it comes to the fgets(), it isn't taking any input. I hope you'd help me out with it. I'm also new to stack overflow, thanks for helping!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("What's your favorite number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Your favorite number is %d.\n", num);

    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s.\n", name);

    char motherName[30];
    printf("Enter your mother's full name: ");
    fgets(motherName, sizeof(motherName), stdin);
    printf("%s is your mom's full name.", motherName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets()` after  `scanf("%s", name);` leads to trouble.  Do not use `scanf()`.  Who suggested `scanf()`?

Comment: It seems the carrige return is added to your input. Have you tried to trim it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, `fgets()` fills the buffer *including* the terminating LF (newline) character.

To dispose of the newline (linefeed) after `fgets()`:

```
#include <string.h> // add this header to use MANY string functions
/* ... */
    fgets(motherName, sizeof motherName, stdin); // "()" unnecessary with sizeof in this usage.
    motherName[ strcspn(motherName, "\n") ] = '\0'; // add this line to obliterate LF
```

---

As for the second problem, it's a wrestling match to use both `scanf()` and `fgets()` together. The former will leave (unexpected) whitespace (including LF) in the buffer. And, as you've done, most code doesn't check that `scanf()` assigned all the values expected.

Now that you're using `fgets()`, stop using `scanf()` for input. The Standard Library contains all the functions you need to separate strings into *tokens* (`strtok()`) and to convert those tokens to `int` (`strtol()`) or `double` (`strtod()`). This is the way the big boys do it.

---

Move away from the keyboard and go learn about the functions provided by the Standard Library.

---

**EDIT**

Your code modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // Added

int main()
{
    char motherName[30];
    printf("Enter your mother's full name: ");
    fgets(motherName, sizeof(motherName), stdin);

    motherName[ strcspn(motherName, "\n") ] = '\0'; // obliterate LF

    printf("Your mom's full name is %s.\n", motherName); // added LF to this output

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter your mother's full name: She who cooks dinner
Your mom's full name is She who cooks dinner.
```

Second problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[ 128 ]; // some size big enough

    printf("What's your favorite number: ");
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );

    int num = strtol( buf, NULL, 10 ); // new function. read doco
    printf("Your favorite number is %d.\n", num);

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
    buf[ strcspn(buf, "\n") ] = '\0'; // << NB
    printf("Your name is %s.\n", buf);

    printf("Enter your mother's full name: ");
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
    buf[ strcspn(buf, "\n") ] = '\0'; // << NB
    printf("%s is your mom's full name.\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
What's your favorite number: 27
Your favorite number is 27.
Enter your name: fe2O3
Your name is fe2O3.
Enter your mother's full name: Marge Simpson
Marge Simpson is your mom's full name.
```

Can't say why you're having problems...

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's giving me out an error. Can you please send the whole code for further clarification?

Comment: Typo... I'd typed apostrophes instead of double quotes on that line... Oops... Try copy/paste again... Or tell exactly what the error is if not that. Which code snippet you posted is giving you the error?

Comment: main.c:9:37: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcspn’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
9 |     motherName[ strcspn(motherName, '\n') ] = '\0';
|                                     ^~~~
|                                     |
|                                     int

Comment: I've admitted my typo in the previous comment... Use double quotes, not single quotes. Change `'\n'` to `"\n"`

Comment: Tried doing exactly what you've said, it is showing me a bunch of errors. Unable to post it here, it is more than the characters permitted here.

Comment: It's working like a charm but it is throwing a warning. Can that be ignored? Is it normal in C?

Comment: @Greeshma What warning? No, warnings are not something to be casually ignored...

Comment: It suggests to use strtok().

Comment: And also suggest me a good website, book or documentation to learn C.

Comment: That would work. It would require splitting one statement into two. You can safely ignore this suggestion... Or take it as an opportunity to explore implementing your code using `strtok()`...

Comment: Recommendations for "good" books are beyond the scope of this website.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

You can just change

```
fgets(motherName, sizeof(motherName), stdin);
```

into

```
scanf("%[^n]", motherName);
```

## Explanation

Using format-input functions like `scanf` with char-input functions like `getchar` or `fgets` will lead to some confusing results,  becasue `scanf` won't consume the trailing `\n`.

Let's if you write just a simple codes to read a word and a line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char word[32];
  char line[32];
  scanf("%s", word);
  fgets(line, 31, stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

Then you input

```
hey
hello world
```

Then scanf will read `hey` and store it into array `word` and left '\n', for which `fgets` just read this `\n` and think "Oh, this is an empty line and I just meets it end". Fianlly, `word` is `hey` and `line` is `\n`.

But how to fix it? You can read all lines by `fgets` and process them manually, or you can just fix this issue with the information above. For example, just use one more `fgets` to read the trailing `\n` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char word[32];
  char line[32];
  scanf("%s", word);
  fgets(line, 31, stdin);  // it will consume the '\n'
  fgets(line, 31, stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

With the same input above, it leads to the result where `word` is `hey` and `line` is `hello world\n`.

However, we will still have two issues:

1. it really ugly to use another `fgets`.
2. `fgets` read the trailing `\n` which is not expected.

If you want to fix them gracefully, I would introduce another trick: negated scanset. You can get the details reference at https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

You choose `fgets` because scanf with `%s` will stop when meeting any space, but you can use negated scanset to prevent `scanf` ends reading unless meeting `\n`. I just show the usage here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char word[32];
  char line[32];
  scanf("%s", word);
  scanf("%[^\n]", line); // The reading only stops once meeting "\n" or EOF
  return 0;
}
```

With the same input above, `word` will be `hey` and `line` will be `hello world`.

Comment: It's plain to see, from your examples, that users of `fgets()` must be aware of buffer sizes, whereas `scanf()` users may as well be using `gets()`... Hacker's love `scanf()`...

Comment: To be more explicit, `scanf` can easily give code that can be broken by a simple buffer overflow. It can be avoided because it is possible to limit the input width (whereas no solution exists for the ugly `gets`) but correctly using `scanf` require user to be *very* cautious. Said differently advising to use `scanf` without specifying the necessary precautions (test the return value and prevent any buffer overflow) is *bad*.